# NestJS TypeORM How to have a ManyToOne relationship member which type is conditionnal?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, relationship, typeorm

I have an entity Message that has a `sender` (`User`) and a `receiver`, but the `receiver` can either be a `User` or a `Channel` (both entities have the `messagesIn` member), and I want to implement this using TypeORM relationships.

Would It be possible to do something like this with TypeORM(postgres)/NestJS (Or is there any conventional other way to achieve the same goal) ?

```js
// message.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Message {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (snd) => snd.messagesOut)
  sender: User;

  // That line doesn't compile
  @ManyToOne(() => User | Channel, (rcv) => rcv.messagesIn)
  receiver: User | Channel;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible because TypeORM needs to know exactly what entity you are trying to populate so then it can query in the right place.

TypeORM has some mechanisms that allows you to create a single table that all the records, both from User and Channel, will be inserted in, see more [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-inheritance).

But, if you want to have two dedicates table for each entity (aka Table Per Type Inheritance), I would suggest create another entity called `Receiver` that contains common properties, that are related to the messaging mechanism, between `User` and `Channel`, plus a property called `type`, that will define if the Receiver is a `User` or a `Channel`; and then reference the `Receiver` entity in each one of the two tables.

```
export enum ReceiverType {
  USER = 'USER',
  CHANNEL = 'CHANNEL',
}

@Entity()
export class Receiver {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  // all common properties that you want related to messaging goes here

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (msg) => msg.receiver)
  messagesIn: Message[];

  @Column({
    type: "enum",
    enum: ReceiverType,
  })
  type: ReceiverType
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  // user properties...

  @OneToOne(() => Receiver)
  @JoinColumn()
  receiver: Receiver
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Channel {
  // channel properties...

  @OneToOne(() => Receiver)
  @JoinColumn()
  receiver: Receiver
}
```

Then, in the `Message` entity, you will be able to reference `Receiver`:

```
@Entity()
export class Message {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (snd) => snd.messagesOut)
  sender: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Receiver, (rcv) => rcv.messagesIn)
  receiver: Receiver;
};
```

So, when you get a Message entity through the repository, you will receive something like:

```
{
  id: string;
  content: string;
  sender: { ... };
  receiver: {
    // common properties you defined...
    messagesIn: [ ... ],
    type: ReceiverType,
  }
}
```

With this information in hands, you will be able to access the data that you want and is necessary for the message sending flow, and, if you need some specific information that is only present in the `User` or `Channel` entity, you can get the `type` from `Receiver` and retrieve the respective entity by the receiver id, something like:

```
if (message.receiver.type === ReceiverType.USER) {
  const user = await userRepository.findOne({
    where: {
      receiver: { id: message.receiver.id },
    },
  });

  ...
}

if (message.receiver.type === ReceiverType.CHANNEL) {
  const user = await channelRepository.findOne({
    where: {
      receiver: { id: message.receiver.id },
    },
  });

  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement it but how can you initialize a receiver at creation of an User/Channel ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is the way that you can initialize it:

`(1) user.receiver = new Receiver();`
`(2) user.receiver.type = ReceiverType.USER;`
`(3) await userRepository.save(user);`

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** have  a column which is a foreign key either of multiple tables; a FK must always reference a specific column/column set in a single table. You handle this situation by defining a nullable column(s) referencing each table, then place a constraint requiring one of them to be null. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with your obscurification manager (TypeORM) so I will also provide a raw Postgres table definition.

```
Create table Message( id          uuid default gen_random_uuid()
                                  primary key
                    , content     text 
                    , sender_user uuid
                                  references users(id) 
                    , rcv_user    uuid 
                                  references users(id) 
                    , rcv_channel uuid 
                                  references channels(id)                   
                    , constraint  only_user_or_channel_ck 
                                  check ( num_nulls(rcv_user,rcv_channel) = 1 )
                    );
```

Of course that makes assumptions about you tables, their keys and column types.